# wordpress: how do actions get executed?

Tags: wordpress, function, action, hook, call

Do custom hooks that hook onto wordpress core get executed automatically by wordpress or do we have to call the `do_action` function on the custom made hook ourselves?

Example:

```
add_action("action_one","some_process",10);
add_action("action_one","some_different_process",11);

function some_process(){ //... }
function some_different_process(){ //... }

do_action("action_one");
```

Does `some_process` get executed first and then `some_different_process` gets executed after when `do_action("action_one")` is called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you create custom action hooks that exist within your custom theme or plugin, then yes, you have to call them via `do_action` in the appropriate location where you would want them to be triggered.

WordPress does not automatically find action hooks and trigger them.  It has a number of built-in hooks which you can latch onto in order to run custom code, but if you create your own hooks, then you need to also set up the appropriate `do_action` call in order to run them.

To answer your other question regarding the execution order of `some_process` and `some_different_process`, `some_process` will be run before `some_different_process` because it had a lower priority number.

If you want an action to run early, give it a low number like 1 or 5, if you don't care where it runs or want it to run last, I usually use a much higher number like 100 or 1000.  If two hooks are defined with the same priority, usually the one that got registered first will run before the other one with the same priority.

Comment: BEST ANSWER!  i can tell your very experienced with wordpress and smart.  ty.

Answer (score 2):

All functions that are hooked onto an action are automatically executed IF that action is called, but they are not called if the action is not triggered.

For example if you have:

```
add_action("action_one","some_function",10);
```

Then `some_function` will be called if `action_one` is triggered. If `action_one` is never triggered, some_function is not called.

`do_action` is a mechanism to manually trigger the action, though keep in mind it will trigger ANY hooks into that action, not just yours (unless you setup some filters).

---

**Another example:** let's say you setup a custom function to run on the action `save_post`:

```
add_action( 'save_post', 'top_secret_function' );
```

Then every time you a save a post your `top_secret_function` will run.

If you want to trigger `save_post` manually (without actually saving a post) you can do so with:

```
do_action( 'save_post' );
```

and it will trigger your `top_secret_function`, but this would generally not be recommended because it will also trigger any other function that is hooked into `save_post` (which many plugins and core files do).

[You can setup custom actions](http://relearningtheweb.blogspot.com/2012/12/wordpress-create-custom-action-hook-in.html) using a combination of `add_action` and `do_action`.

Comment: so in general actions are meant for wordpress to trigger, not the programmer correct?

Comment: neither? It all depends on which action you hook into, your function, how it's being used, etc. etc. you can setup custom actions using a combination: http://relearningtheweb.blogspot.com/2012/12/wordpress-create-custom-action-hook-in.html

Comment: but I think you are getting the concept - if you hook into a wordpress action then wordpress will eventually call your function when the action is called. You can just manually call that action with do_action if you need to.

Comment: what if you create a custom action hook that does not hook onto a wordpress action?